# In excel with python, how do you find words, from an entire column, in a cell containing multiple words?

Tags: python, excel, list

I have an excel file with a list of KEY words in column A.

```
eg. Bob
    Dan
    Brian
```

In column B i have a few rows with multiple entries in a cell:

```
B1= Bob, Grant, James, Dave
B2= Dean, Dan, Brian
```

How do i out put into column C and names that are in column A and cell B.
i.e. i would like an ouput that is:

```
C1= Bob
C2= Dan, Brian
```

Any ideas? Ive tried using python but not sure how to start.

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What have you tried?

This might be somewhere to start: http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/

Comment: @gene onyx: you have not commented on my answer or here, have you found an answer? if so, could you close this question?

Comment: Thanks for the above link deadly. So much to take in all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It first depends on the Python module you are using to access Excel. If you are using Windows I would recommend using Win32Com which can be found [here.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20217/) This module gives Python programmatic access to any Microsoft Office Application (including Excel) and uses many of the same methods used in VBA.

Here is the solution to your problem using Win32Com for Excel. I am assuming that you are using a comma (',') as your delimiter between names AND that your match on names between column A and column B is case sensitive (remember that in Python "A" does not equal "a")

To start we want to connect to Excel and get access to the sheet with your names

```
#First we need to access the module that lets us connect to Excel
import win32com.client 

# Next we want to create a variable that represents Excel
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")   

# Lastly we will assume that the sheet with the names is the active sheet
sheet = app.ActiveSheet
```

At this point we have a variable named *sheet* that represents the active excel work sheet with the names. You can activate the sheet simply by clicking on any cell. Now we want to start by getting all of the names in Column A and storing it to a list. We have two options for doing this:

1. We can iterate over all of the Cells in Column A and extract the name stored a as a string and append it to a list of all names using *sheet.Cells(row,col).Value.* This works just fine with smaller ranges, but can be slow if you are dealing with 500+ rows.
2. We can extract the entire range of cells in Column A that contains the names using      *sheet.Range("A1","A3").Value* and add the values to the list. This can be much faster if you have a large range of cells. For this example we will use Range.

Example Continued:

```
import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")   
sheet = app.ActiveSheet

# rang is an object representing the cells A1, A2, A3
rang = sheet.Range("A1","A3")

# names is a tuple of length 3 containing tuples of length 2
names = rang.Value

#nameLst is a list of all values in names
nameLst = [name[0] for name in names]
```

Next we want to iterate over all of the names in Column B. For this we are going to use the sheet.Cells.Value function to get the list of names of each cell in Col B. We are also going to use the string.split(",") function to split the comma delimited names into a list of the names and string.strip() to remove any unnecessary whitespace. If any of the names in this list are in nameLst, we know we have a match and will put it in Col C.

```
import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")   
sheet = app.ActiveSheet

rang = sheet.Range("A1","A3")
names = rang.Value
nameLst = [name[0] for name in names]

#Iterate over the rows ic ColB. Remember Excel uses base 1 not 0 for inexing
for rowI in range(1,3):
    cellNames = sheet.Cells(rowI,2).Value

    #split cellNames by "," and add all of the names to a list.
    cellNamesLst = [cellName.strip() for cellName in cellNames.split(",")]

    #Now we want a list of all names that are in cellNamesLst and in nameLst
    matchLst = [matchName for matchName in cellNamesLst if matchName in nameLst]

    #Create a string of all matches to go in Col C
    allMatches = ", ".join(matchLst)

    #Lastly put all matches in in Col C
    sheet.Cells(rowI,3).Value = allMatches
```

This will will put the string "Bob" into Cell C1 and "Dan, Brian" into cell C2. The use of win32com can be very powerful and can be used to automate much of what you do in all of MS Office applications.

Here is the Final Code w/o comments:

```
import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")   
sheet = app.ActiveSheet

rang = sheet.Range("A1","A3")
names = rang.Value
nameLst = [name[0] for name in names]

for rowI in range(1,3):
    cellNames = sheet.Cells(rowI,2).Value
    cellNamesLst = [cellName.strip() for cellName in cellNames.split(",")]
    matchLst = [matchName for matchName in cellNamesLst if matchName in nameLst]
    allMatches = ", ".join(matchLst)
    sheet.Cells(rowI,3).Value = allMatches
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Michael. This worked an absolute treat!?! And most importantly thanks for the novice guide through it with the step by step explained.

Comment: No problem Onyx. I remember when I started using Python for Excel, PowerPoint, Word and Access and it was really difficult to put all of the information together. If you have any more questions feel free to shoot me a message and I can see how I can help.

Answer (score 0):

as i see it, the "columns" and their "cells" are simply lists.

```
#the "columns"

A = ["Bob","Dan","Brian"]
B = [["Bob", "Grant", "James", "Dave"],\
     ["Dean", "Dan", "Brian"]]
C = []


for b in B:
    c = []
    for name in b:
        if name in A:
            c.append(name)
    C.append(c)

for c in C:
    print c

>>> 
['Bob']
['Dan', 'Brian']
```

all you need to do is read each column to a list. for column A simply append the items as a list of names. and for column B simply append each cell as its own list to the main list.

and there you have it.

Comment: Doh, it looks so simple. When i had a go it wasnt like that.

Comment: @Onyx thats python, it can be very simple if you want it to be. also - you dont even need special excel readers, just read the file and split the lines to get each column type. if you want i can add that to my answer if you are having trouble.